# jquery directory tree

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jquery for listing directory's and I would like to inplement delete check box in it and delete submit buton by every directory on the tree . How to do that? 
I'm using this code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>jQuery Drop Down Menu</title> 

<!-- CSS For The Menu --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylee.css" /> 

</head> 
<body> 

<!-- Menu Start --> 
<div id="jQ-menu"> 

<?php
error_reporting(0);
    $path = "store/".$diro."/";

    function createDir($path = '.')
    {   
        if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
        {
            echo "<ul>";

            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
            {
                if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file !='..')
                    printSubDir($file, $path, $queue);
                else if ($file != '.' && $file !='..')
                    $queue[] = $file;
            }

            printQueue($queue, $path);
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }

    function printQueue($queue, $path)
    {
        foreach ($queue as $file) 
        {
            printFile($file, $path);
        } 
    }

    function printFile($file, $path)
    {
        echo "<li><a href=\"".$path.$file."\">$file</a></li>";
    }

    function printSubDir($dir, $path)
    {
        echo "<li><span class=\"toggle\">$dir</span>";
        createDir($path.$dir."/");
        echo "</li>";
    }

    createDir($path);
?>

</div> 
<!-- End Menu --> 


<!-- Add jQuery From the Google AJAX Libraries --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery Color Plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js"></script> 

<!-- Import The jQuery Script --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jMenu.js"></script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to an example where we can see this tree-menu in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it exactly you want the user to be able to do with the tree, and how should it react? On a hunch, I see at least two ways you could go. You could output the html for the checkboxes and buttons straight away, and later add behaviour to them using selectors, or you could output the tree first and then after document.ready modify the dom by using jquery's DOM modification such as before().

Depending on the functions you want, it could be something like:

```
function printFile($file, $path)
{
    echo "<li class='fileNode'><a href=\"".$path.$file."\">$file</a></li>";
}
function printSubDir($dir, $path)
{
    echo "<li class='dirNode'><span class=\"toggle\">$dir</span>";
    createDir($path.$dir."/");
    echo "</li>";
}
```

And then in your JavaScript do something like

```
$(document).ready(function
{
    // you should still assign some behaviour probably
    $(".fileNode").prepend("<input type='checkbox' />");
});
```

Or you could just make sure that the checkboxes are already present and you could bind some ajax function to the checkbox' change(). http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Ok I want that user can delete the files from his directory tree that is uniq for that user ...Sou I'm no longer using this code for that ...Im using this code from this web site http://code.google.com/p/editable-jquery-tree-with-php-codes/ becos ther is allredy the delete function on the directory tree BUT THER IS THE PROBLEM WITH THAT CODE  ...TAKE A LOOK ON THE MY QUESTORN ON THE PROBLEM USING THE DEFINE FUNCTION ...First look the directory tree from the web site http://code.google.com/p/editable-jquery-tree-with-php-codes/ then my question... If you can help please contact mee ...

Answer (score 0):

Check this
https://github.com/zTree/zTree_v3
its very easy to use